# What is the difference between globally declaring a function and using window.myfunc = myfunc

Tags: javascript, unobtrusive-javascript

What is the difference between the following 2 examples of code:

```
(function(){
    var myFunc = (function(){
        //do something
    })();
    window.myFunc = myFunc;
})();
```

and

```
var myFunc = (function(){
    //do something
})();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two ways are really similar, but there is a small difference on how the `myFunc` global variable is created.

In the second way, using the `var` statement, will create the `myFunc` variable as a non-deleteable property of the global object, the var statement explicitly sets the internal `{DontDelete}` attribute , e.g.:

```
var myFunc = (function(){
    //do something
})();

delete window.myFunc; // false
```

While the first one can be deleted:

```
(function(){
    var myFunc = (function(){
        //do something
    })();
    window.myFunc = myFunc;
})();

//...
delete window.myFunc; // true
```

If you try the above in Firebug, both can be deleted, thats because Firebug uses code evaluation (`eval`) in the console.

You can check the above example [here](http://jsbin.com/uxapu/3).

Recommended article:

- [Understanding delete](http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/)

Comment: so when would you want, or need, to delete something from the global object?

Comment: @Russ: Well, a common practice is to simply set them to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Semantically nothing. However, the first example you can have "private" functions that can make your code more readable.

Take this example:

```
(function(){
    var helperFunc = function()
    {
        //do something else
    }
    var myFunc = function(){
        //do something
        helperFunc();
    }
    window.myFunc = myFunc;
})();
```

Cleaner code results in the hands of a good developer